# Koken & Chrome: INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: nginx, koken

Some albums do not load using koken and I get this error INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING on Chrome. I'm using nginx 1.6.2, CentOS 7, Koken 0.22.4. I'm using graphicsMagick 1.3.23, ImageMagick 6.9.2, PHP 5.6.21 and MySQL 5.1.73.

[Related issue](http://help.koken.me/customer/portal/questions/16269350)

Answer (score 0):

After checking some related issues about INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING like:

- This on the [apache help blog](http://apachehelp.filegala.com/2015/04/27/chrome-neterr_incomplete_chunked_encoding-error/)
- [Another one here](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/341#issuecomment-158247405)
- [And finally this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789268/neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-nginx)

I solved it by changing the permissions on my /opt/nginx directory to the nginx user. It may be related with the last referenced post.

> when you give a response too big for Nginx, it uses this directory to
>   write as a working directory for temporary files. If the worker
>   process cannot access it, Nginx will terminate the transmission before
>   it completes, thus the error INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING.