# net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

> angular.js:8632 POST http://alpha.openworldinsurance.com/om-valuelists-api/rest/valuelists/UnifiedCity/mappings net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
>
> angular.js:8632 POST http://alpha.openworldinsurance.com/om-valuelists-api/rest/valuelists/CignaProductData/generalmaster net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

The above error occurs when a web-service is consumed and more amount of data is returned by the server. Any solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check the upvoted answer in this question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789268/neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-nginx Hope it helps!

Comment: any solution for this? I am having the same issue with large amount of data. please help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx in between then it's is probably a problem with nginx permission.
Try this

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/nginx/
$ sudo nginx -s stop
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/var/run/nginx/
$ sudo chown nobody:nobody /usr/local/var/run/nginx/
$ sudo nginx
```