# ningx+php: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: php, nginx

Within the last week or so I have started getting this error in Chrome

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

My application is developed in PHP.. Have tried to search the whole code base for `Content-Length` (case in-sensitive) to check if I set it somewhere manually in the code.. But I don't.. And I haven't made any changes in the code since the issue started

Webserver i Nginx

Have someone else than me experienced this issue?

```
# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.13.6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_CONTENT\_LENGTH\_MISMATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521839/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-content-length-mismatch)

Comment: I agree with Dez - most likely this is a nginx / proxy problem and has nothing to do with your PHP app. It could be a caching problem (disable cache altogether and see if it goes away?).