# CkEditor.js "ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH" Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

My project is run locally but when I install it on the server I get this error. "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH" and ckeditor.js not loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_CONTENT\_LENGTH\_MISMATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521839/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-content-length-mismatch)

Comment: This error is not related to CKEditor but rather to server configuration. I recommend googling for `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` as it pops out in quite a few questions. In general there is a discrepancy between the content length declared in the header and the actual length of transferred content.