# net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have the following problem loading dependency via Requirejs

> http://mysite/dist/js/vendor/leaflet.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)
>   Uncaught Error: Script error for "leaflet", needed by: app

```
    "use strict";

    requirejs.config({
      "baseUrl": typeof siteRoot !== "undefined" ? siteRoot + 
    "dist/js" : "./dist/js",
      "paths": {
        "choices": "./vendor/choices",
        "handlebars": "./vendor/handlebars",
        "leaflet": "./vendor/leaflet",
        "navigo": "./vendor/navigo",
        "nouislider": "./vendor/nouislider",
        "glide": "./vendor/glide",
        "app": "app"
      }
    });
    define(["app"], function (App) {
     App.init();
    });
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Comment: Take a look at this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521839/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-content-length-mismatch seems that your problem is not related to RequireJS :)