# How to send data from html to controller and reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, controller, cgi, reload

I have written a code for sending data from webpage to controller. I am not a html guy and I have written using some templates. I have created a form and I wanted to send the baudrate value to controller.

```
<TABLE width=50%>
    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD width=80%>
                <TABLE width=80%>
                    <TBODY>
                        <TD>
                        <FORM name="baudrate" action="baudrate.cgi" method="get">
                            <TABLE width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                                <TBODY>
                                    <TR>
                                        <TD align=center><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt" face=Arial>&nbsp;<B>Baud Rate:</B></FONT></TD>
                                        <TD align=center height=25><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt" face=Arial>&nbsp;<!--#p0br--> bits/second</FONT></TD>
                                        <TD><FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt" face=Arial>&nbsp;<select size="1" name="br"><option value="230400">230400</option><option value="115200">115200</option><option value="57600">57600</option><option value="38400">38400</option><option value="19200">19200</option><option value="14400">14400</option><option value="9600">9600</option><option value="4800">4800</option><option value="2400">2400</option><option value="1200">1200</option><option value="600">600</option><option value="300">300</option><option value="110">110</option></select>&nbsp;bits/S<br></FONT></TD>
                                    </TR>
                                    <TR>
                                        <TD></TD>
                                        <TD align="center"><input name="" value="Apply" onclick="window.history.go(0); return false; "type="submit"></TD>
                                    </TR>
                                </TBODY>
                            </TABLE>
                        </FORM>
                        </TD>
                    </TBODY>
                </TABLE>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>    
</TABLE>
```

In the above code,
On clicking the submit I wanted to send the br value to the controller by calling the **baudrate.cgi** function and I wanted to reload the page.
If I give

```
<TD align="center"><input name="" value="Apply" onclick="window.history.go(0) "type="submit" ></TD>
```

Then the webpage is **able to send to controller** and the **reload is also happening** but it is only happening in **microsoft edge** browser and in other browsers it is giving error.
If I use 

Then the **webpage is not able to send the data** to the controller but **it is refreshing** in all the browsers.

Is there any other way to achieve this ?
Can anyone please help me?

Regards,
Vibhu.

Comment: Could you specify what error is thrown? Can your `.cgi` file redirect you to the current page to make it reload?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier It is showing "This page isnt working, It didnt send any data". I tried to handle it in .cgi but I was not able to figure that out so I was hoping to solve the issue in the html side.

Answer (score 1):

Use an AJAX request that sends and receives that data through JavaScript. This way you can create your own logic on what will happen when you submit the form. If I understand correctly, you want the following:

```
submit form -> send data to controller -> get response -> reload page
```

First of all, remove the `onclick` event handler. It will interfere with our new listener that will fire a HTTP request to the server. Add a JS file to your HTML or write all JS inside a `<script>` element. Just put them at the bottom of the page before the closing `</body>` tag.

So in barebones, your form is like the example below.

```
<form name="baudrate" action="baudrate.cgi" method="get">

  ...

  <select size="1" name="br">
    <option value="230400">230400</option>
    <option value="115200">115200</option>
    <option value="57600">57600</option>
    <option value="38400">38400</option>
    <option value="19200">19200</option>
    <option value="14400">14400</option>
    <option value="9600">9600</option>
    <option value="4800">4800</option>
    <option value="2400">2400</option>
    <option value="1200">1200</option>
    <option value="600">600</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
    <option value="110">110</option>
  </select>

  ...

</form>
```

You'll need to select the `form` element and add an event listener to it. This is similar to doing `onclick` but now with the `addEventListener` method. This method allows you to bind multiple functions to a single event instead just having one.

Listen for the `submit` event. This event will be triggered whenever a form has been, you guessed it, submitted. An `input type="submit"` or `button type="submit"` is required for this to work properly.

Now in the function which you will fire whenever a `submit` on your form is fired will contain the logic for the AJAX call to the server. You'll need to get the current value of the `select name="br"` element and send it to the `baudrate.cgi` controller. So the url for the AJAX call should look something like this: `'baudrate.cgi?br=14400'`.

Whenever you send the request, two things can happen. Either you get a response, and hopefully a good one, or you get an error.

In case of a succesful response use `location.reload()` to reload the page.
In case of an error, simply log it and debug your `.cgi` code to make it work properly.

I suggest that you try the example below. Like I mentioned above, add a `.js` file to the HTML or paste the JS into a `<script>` tag. And remember to place it at the bottom of the page.

Let me know if this works out and if it is of any help.

```
// Select the form element.
const form = document.querySelector('form[name="baudrate"]');

// Listen for when the form submits.
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  // Cancel the default submit.
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get the value from the select element and add it 
  // to the url to send it to the .cgi file.
  const select = form.elements['br'];
  const url = 'baudrate.cgi?br=' + select.value;

  // Send the data and get a response.
  fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 200) { // If it is a successful response.
      return response.text();
    }
  }).then(function(text) {
    console.log(text); // Show the response from the server.
    location.reload(); // Reload the page.
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error); // If anything went wrong, show the error.
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi Emiel, Thanks. I created one .js file and pasted the code which you have suggested and I am getting the same error as "The page did not receive any response". Should I send any response from the controller side? If yes, what type of response should I send ?

Comment: If I send some random text as response and the response status as 200, The page becomes blank and nothing is displayed on the page if I click on submit.

Comment: If I send the response, sometimes when I click on submit it downloads baudrate.cgi file.

Comment: I am getting the URL like this: 'baudrate.cgi?br=14400', But before the .js file also I was getting the same URL. How should I confirm whether it is calling the .js file ? How do we know whether it is taking the .js file or `<form name="baudrate" action="baudrate.cgi" method="get">` this action to call baudrate.cgi?

Comment: Should I edit anything in the form block in the html? I just removed the `onclick` in the html and the others are the same.

Comment: Did you remember to remove the `onclick` handler on the submit button? You should return a response that tells you if the opration on the server side has been successful or not. Either way it's a status of 200. If anything goes wrong try to check the console for errors. Also check the console if the `fetch` request gets the right URL to your `.cgi` file. In chrome you can opt in for logging *XMLHTTPRequests` to see those requests. Maybe try adding a slash to the front of the URL, like: `/baudrate.cgi?br=14400`. If the page does nog reload on submit, the JS is working.

Comment: I removed the onclick handler. When I tried to check the console for errors, It showed error in `const form = document.querySelector('form[name="baudrate"]`);` this line. I changed the quotes and now it is showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` Error.

Comment: Before changing it was `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` on that line which I mentioned

Comment: After I give apply `GET http://192.168.1.165/baudrate.cgi?br=38400 net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)` this error comes.

Comment: I solved `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener'` this issue by adding `if(form){
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {}}` But I still get the length mismatch error. How to solve it ?

Comment: My apologies, I overlooked the wrong `'` in the querySelector. The updated code should not give an error. About the content mismatch. According to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521839/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-content-length-mismatch) it is caused because your server having a faulty set `Content-Length` header in your response. See it as the response is a letter. And on the front of the letter it says what is inside that letter. But the content of the letter is different than what the front says. But I'm afraid my knowledge is limited to JavaScript.